# Sending my research proposal for a professor or offering to work on their project?

Tags: research-process, masters, professorship

I am trying to contact with professors to showing them a research proposal that I want to work on for master degree. Some people advice me to not do this, because professors get fund for their ideas not mine, so if my research proposal was incredibly liked by a professor, then he will have no fund to do this research project. So, I should contacting to offer working on **their** research ideas. I am not insisting to work on my idea, and to be honest my main goal is to reach a research project in brain computer interface field(I'm interested in any research project in that field) and I'm sure that I will show a great effort, hard working and innovative thinking, Which will supporting me to get a PHD position.

Have saying this; how to know future research projects for a professor to offer working on? or it's possible to work on  project in progress.

Answer (score 2):

Professors can get funding for projects if they write proposals for funding and the proposals are accepted. There are sources for funding for student projects in many places. I do not know about your specific situation, but I don't see why you wouldn't be able to approach the professor about your idea. If it's really good, the professor will help you find funding for it. If it is just good, the professor may have you find funding for it.

Full disclosure - I am a professor. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Professors are primarily interested in people working on *their* projects... that is what they get funding for. They might be interested in your idea, and help you find funding.